# How to count the number of if-statements in a separate file of code

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write a scheme program that counts the number of if-statement a file containing code. I know how to read in the file but I don't know how to go about counting the number of if-statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very hard without actually implementing reducing the language to a more primitive form. As an example, imagine this:

```scm
(count-ifs '(let ((if +))
              (if 1 2 3)))
; ==> 0
```

`0` is the correct amount as `if` is a binding shadowing `if` and Scheme supports shadowing so the result of that expression is `6` and not `2`. `let` can be rewritten such that you can check this instead:

```scm
(count-ifs '((lambda (if) 
               (if 1 2 3)) 
             +))
; ==> 0
```

It might not look like an improvement, but here you can actually fix it:

```scm
(define (count-ifs expr)
  (let helper ((expr expr) (count 0))
    (if (or (not (list? expr))
            (and (eq? (car expr) 'lambda)
                 (memq 'if (cadr expr))))
        count
        (foldl helper
               (if (eq? (car expr) 'if)
                   (add1 count)
                   count)
               expr))))



(count-ifs '((lambda (if) 
               (if 1 2 3)) 
             (if #t + (if if if))))
; ==> 2
```

Challenge is to expand the macros. You actually need to make a macro expander to rewrite the code such that the only form making bindings would be `lambda`. This is the same amount of work as making 80% of a Scheme compiler since once you've dumbed it down the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it could be recursion structure like this:

```
(define (count-ifs exp)
  (+ (if-expression? exp 1 0)))
     (if (pair? exp)
         (+ (count-ifs (car exp)) (count-ifs (cdr exp))))
         0)))
```

But this might overcount.

A more correct way to do it would be to process the code by checking each type of expression you see - and when you enter a lambda you need to add the variables it binds to a shadowed symbols list.